# Who lives in Mount Olympus usually?

Tags: greek, olympus

[Greek gods were on Olympus.](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/511/why-were-the-greek-gods-on-olympus)

On the top of my head, I can also name some more, like the Muses and Ganymede, but, are there other people who lived on Mount Olympus?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the Horai (as they guarded the gates of Olympus).

Answer (score 2):

When you think of Olympus, your mind usually goes straight to the big twelve:  Zeus, Hera, Poseidon, Demeter, Athena, Apollo, Artemis, Ares, Aphrodite, Hephaestus, Hermes, and either Hestia or Dionysus.

However there are Minor residents as well. Ganymede and the Horae are indeed found on Mount Olympus, as well as many others (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Olympians#Minor_residents_of_Mount_Olympus) for a list). They aren't technically counted as "Olympians" but they reside on Mount Olympus.